# Google Sheets API token not renewing automatically in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

I created a program using Python with the Google Sheets API. The problem is that after a while the program says that the token has expired and it cannot automatically refresh the token, so I have to manually delete the token and redo the credentials.Below is the function intended for credentials:

```
def cred():
  creds = None
  
  if os.path.exists("token.json"):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
  if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
      creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
      flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
          "credentials.json", SCOPES
      )
      creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open("token.json", "w") as token:
      token.write(creds.to_json())
  service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds)
   
  return service
```

I need the python code not to stop because of credentials, as it is an automated program and this can create a problem in the data flow.

Comment: What exactly is the problem when you try to automatically refresh the token?

Comment: Is your code saving the refresh token in `token.json`? If not, then offline access was not granted, so fix that. If yes, continue reading. Not possible. To recreate the OAuth Access Token the OAuth Refresh Token is used to make the request. Refresh tokens can be invalidated for many reasons. You must design for that situation and re-authenticate.